# PHP: Pass parameter to function, but with variables defined inside function used in parameter

Tags: php, function

I would like to pass a parameter to a function.  However, inside this parameter, I use variables that are defined inside the function.
For example:

```
<?php

function foo($var){
    $test = "test";
    echo $var;
}

foo($test);

?>
```

In this example, I would like for the function to print out "test".  Of course, this returns an error.  However, this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: That does not seems to make a lot of sense to me... why would you want to do this? (it's not possible btw, unless you make `$test` global, which defeats the purpose of defining it inside the function). Variables defined inside function should stay local, not accessible to the outside, to keep the code decoupled.

Comment: The function contains a foreach, with foreach($array as $post), and I'm using the variable $post in the parameter.

Comment: Why are you passing `$post` as argument? Or do you mean the parameter name is `$post`? `$post` will be populated with each element in `$array` during the loop. I still don't understand and I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with using [`variable-variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), though I don't understand why you'd want/need to:

```
function foo($var){
    $test = "test";
    echo $$var;
}

foo('test');
```

Notice in the `echo` statement inside `foo()`, the variable has two `$` leading. This is a `variable-variable` and `$var`'s *value* will be treated as a variable-name. So, by calling `foo('test');` (the parameter being a string in this case), `$$var` will evaluate to `$test`.

Comment: @Sang: Note that using variable variables is generally a poor design choice. If you would explain which problem you are actually trying to solve, we could help you better.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe also it could be better, however variable-variables working also ... I agree with you, if he provides an original part of code, it would be much better for him at least.